# Get sub collection firestore user login

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I access a sub collection of a specific document in Firestore?

I have created users with and I am storing them in a `users` collection. Now every user when they log in I am getting their respective data `displayName` and `email` in the following way:

```
this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
     return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()
    } else {
      return of(null)
    }
  })
)
```

The structure looks more or less like this:

```
users:{
  userID1: { displayName: 'name1', email: 'email1@mail.com'

    favorites: {
      favoriteID1: { title: 'title1', description: 'description1' },
      favoriteID2: { title: 'title2', description: 'description2' }
    }
  },
  userID2: { displayName: 'name2', email: 'email2@mail.com' },
  userID3: { displayName: 'name3', email: 'email3@mail.com' },


}
```

How can I access the `favorites` sub collection only for that user who has logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Using Firestore you can access collections within a document reference see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#collection

so it would be something like `db.collection("users").doc("id").collection("favorites").get()`
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md

You can do `.collection<Foo>('foos')` on an AngularFirestoreDocument.

Method A:

```js
this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      let userDoc = this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`);
      this.user$ = userDoc.valueChanges();
      this.userFavs$ = userDoc.collection<Favorite>('favorites').valueChanges();
    } else {
      this.user$ = of(null);
      this.userFavs$ = of(null);
    }
  })
);
```

Method B:

```js
this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
    } else {
      return of(null);
    }
  })
);

this.userFavs$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    if (user) {
      let userDoc = this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`);
      return userDoc.collection<Favorite>('favorites').valueChanges();
    } else {
      return of(null);
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: when I run it like this: `(users / HyrKcs4ScucHDFDrT6AdckugOSt2)` works fine, but when I include `(` users/${user.uid}`)` I get the following error: `[ts] The 'uid' property does not exist in the 'Observable <User>' type`. I have a `User` interface that does have the `uid` field

Comment: Is `HyrKcs4ScucHDFDrT6AdckugOSt2` a User document ID or a Firebase User uid?

Comment: Yes, it is the id of a user document

Comment: Check my updated answer. Use either one, depending on which you prefer. Let me know if you get any more errors.